# serialize a form and send the serialized data with ajax using POST method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm trying to serialize a form and send the serialized data with ajax using POST method ..

> index.php

```
<form id ="form" class = "form">
        <input type = "text" name = "name" />           
        <input type = "number" name = "age" />
        <input type = "number" name = "id" />
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit"><br/>
</form>
<p id = "result"></p>
```

> Jquery snippets

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){
            var data = $("#form").serialize();
            insertStudent(data);
            return false ;
        });
        function insertStudent(data){
            $.post("process.php" , { data : data} , function(str){
            $("#result").html(str);
            });                 
        }
   });
</script>
```

> process.php

```
$ret = $_POST["data"];
echo "<br />".$ret["name"];
```

And now , the result is :

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\try.php on line 3

When i tried to echo $_POST["data"] the result is :

> name=Ahmed&age=111&id=222

how can i use every name individually such as : $_POST["name"] ... $_POST["age"] ... $_POST["id"] ?

Comment: GET is the default for forms, you have no `method='post'`

Comment: @Dagon the $.post is alternative to the attribute method='post'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function insertStudent(data){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(str){
                 $("#result").html(str);
            }
        });     
    }
```

And then print $_POST in your PHP file :)

Comment: how to catch each element alone  in PHP file

Comment: print_r($_POST);  and you will see :) They will come as normal post array, access them $_POST['name']... e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you send the data to the server:

```
{data: data}
```

turns your serialised data into one parameter in stead of a series of parameters, that serialize() collects. Just change it to:

```
data
```

EDIT (added explicit example):
The following (and the above) works. If it does not work for you, you have other errors in your php code.

index.php:

```
    <?php
echo '<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){

            var data = $("#form").serialize();
            insertStudent(data);
            return false ;
        });
        function insertStudent(data){

            $.post("process.php" , data , function(str){
            $("#result").html(str);

            });                 
        }
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>test of form</p>
<form id ="form" class = "form">
        <input type = "text" name = "name" />           
        <input type = "number" name = "age" />
        <input type = "number" name = "id" />
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit"><br/>
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

process.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br/>"; 
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.": '".$value."'<br/>";
}
?>
```

results in the output:

```
Array ( [name] => Whatevernameyoutype [age] => whateverageyoutype [id] => whateveridyoutype ) 
name: 'Whatevernameyoutype'
age: 'whateverageyoutype'
id: 'whateveridyoutype'
```

Instead of the loop, you can access any of the posted parameters with $_POST["KEYNAMEHERE"];

Comment: Try again with the above. If you still get an error message, something else is wrong with your php code.